# Problem with citation number when using the cite package

Tags: cite-package

I was using the `cite` package and encountered a problem with it. The citation number sometimes remains "[?]"; even after several compiling cycles. Here is MWE and its outcome:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cite}

\begin{document}
This is a MWE. This citation~\cite{foo} works correctly but this one~\cite{bib: bar} doesn't.

\begin{thebibliography}{2}
\bibitem{foo} foo
\bibitem{bib: bar} bar
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]

It seems this problem occurs when `\bibitem`'s parameter includes space like `\bibitem{bib: bar} bar`.

Can anyone solve this problem?

P.S. Further information such as an solution without abondoning my habit would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you need the space for in `bibitem{bib: bar}`?

Comment: It's merely my habit. I always write labels and bibliography items like `\label{eq: foo}` or `\label{fig: foo}` in order to give the same name to different objects (equation, figure, table, etc.).

Comment: Regarding your P.S.: With the solution I showed you, you can still write `\cite{bib: bar}` in the manuscript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Problem is that `\cite` eats the spacetokens when writing to the main auxiliary file; i.e., even if you say `\cite{bib: bar}` the resulting entry in the `.aux` would look like `\citation{bib:bar}`. But, when the engine is looking for `\bibcite{bib:bar}...` it won't find anything because `\bibitem` preserves all the spaces in the input.

You can **leave** the citations in the desired form, e.g. `\cite{bib: bar}` if you don't want to abandon your labeling habit, *but* you have to write `\bibitem{bib:bar} ...` in the `thebibliography` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cite}

\begin{document}
This is a MWE. This citation~\cite{foo} works correctly and this one~\cite{bib: bar} too, though there is a space in between the label name. 

\begin{thebibliography}{2}
\bibitem{foo} foo
\bibitem{bib:bar} bar
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The reason I write labels in this style is that I think putting words after colon without space is grammatically incorrect. Anyway I understood why my MWE didn't work.

Comment: The interpunction-space-rule you are refering to holds for typeset text. It is insignificant in the coding layer. Notice that "bib: bar" in your cite instruction is a macro argument and it does not have to be in line with the rule you mentioned.

Comment: @Merzong Spaces are generally not a good idea in anything 'programmatic': code labels have their own grammar entirely independent of 'natural' language (think CamelCaseCommandNames or names_with_underscores).